# clearInterval not working with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the result, next time of the game in database. I used XMLHttpRequest with 5s delay of setInterval to fetch data. If the status of the request is 200. The code works well. However, if the status is not 200. The clearInterval will not work but console.log still works.

```
var _resInterval;
_resInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/index.php/forms/getDDResult/" + id, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var _resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(_resp);

      if (parseInt(_resp.interval) >= 0) {
        clearInterval(_resInterval);
        restartGame(parseInt(_resp.interval));
      }
    } else {
      console.log("error");
      clearInterval(_resInterval);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}, 5000);
```

**UPDATE: recursive function**

```
function getGameResult() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/index.php/forms/getDDResult/" + id, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var _resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(_resp);

      if (parseInt(_resp.interval) >= 0 && _resp.result != "Not available") {
        restartGame(parseInt(_resp.interval));
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
          getGameResult();
        }, 5000);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Am I doing it the right way or should I change it to recursive function? Thanks.

-- Lara

Comment: What do you mean by "the clearInterval will not work"?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Hi, thanks for giving time to my question. clearInterval will stop the setInterval, right? It doesn't stop from running the code. I'm not sure if using recursive function is good for this kind of situation but recursive worked well for me. Waiting for some javascript heroes to share knowledge :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there's a possibility where the `clearInterval` is called and an XHR is pending a response. When the browser receives the response, the timer is long gone, but still has to handle the response.

If you want your periodic XHR to wait for the response of the previous before launching another, the recursive `setTimeout` is a better option.

Comment: Thanks Joseph for your answer. I really appreciated it. Now, I'm going to use the recursive timeout.